# Nginx vhost on non-standard port not working

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, varnish

I am attempting to use varnish as a front-end proxy to Nginx.

When I attempt to using the following as my vhost configuration:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name playwithbits.com  www.playwithbits.com;

  # limit_conn limit_per_ip 16;
  # ssi  on;

  access_log /home/nginx/domains/playwithbits/log/access.log combined buffer=32k;
  error_log /home/nginx/domains/playwithbits/log/error.log;

  root /home/nginx/domains/playwithbits/public;

  location / {

  # Enables directory listings when index file not found
  #autoindex  on;

  # Shows file listing times as local time
  #autoindex_localtime on;

  # Enable for vBulletin usage WITHOUT vbSEO installed
  #try_files             / /index.php;

  }

  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
  #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;
}
```

However this stops working when I specify `listen 8080` and redirects to the default nginx web root (as specified in `virtual.conf`), if I remove that line it works as expected and redirects to the correct directory.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can set a non-standard port for my vhost so varnish can listen on port 80.

Comment: Did you do `nginx -t` to check nginx config when `listen 8080;` was specified?

Comment: @hangover Cheers, didn't know about that. It returns `nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't Nginx, it was Wordpress. Apparently WordPress redirects itself and you have to put the port extension onto the `WordPress Address (URL)` setting in the dashboard like so:

`http://playwithbits.com:8080`

And it works, otherwise WordPress redirects to port 80 causing my default Nginx configuration to kick in.